# How do I know which key is pressed?

Tags: c++, windows

I was wondering that how do I know which key is pressed from my keyboard.? A read a couple of website about GetAsyncKeyState() but I still didn't get how this function works. Anyone please explain this with example.

Comment: Are you asking in general (which would explain why you were unable to get it to work), or specifically about [the Windows function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: I am programming in windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows, you can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE))
        {
            printf("Delete has been pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I have to detect multiple keys, then I have to use this function multiple times?

Comment: @nkd2195: You can get the status of all virtual keys at once with `GetKeyboardState`. But note that this requires you to process the keyboard messages that are sent to your thread's message queue. To quote MSDN: _"The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads."_.

Answer (score 1):

For more virtual key code visit this ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx )

```
  #include <iostream> 
  #include <windows.h> 
  #include <winuser.h> 
     using namespace std; 
     int Stroke (int key_stroke);

    int main() 
    { 
       char i;
       while (1)
        {
           for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
            {
              if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
              Stroke (i); 
             }
        }
       return 0;
     }

   int Stroke (int key_stroke)
   {
     if ( (key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2) )
     return 0;
     if (key_stroke == 8)
     printf("%s\n", "[BACKSPACE]"); 
     else if (key_stroke == 13)
     printf("%s\n", "[ENTER]\n"); 
     else if (key_stroke == 32)
     printf("%s\n", "[SPACE]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_TAB) 
     printf("%s\n", "[TAB]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_SHIFT)
     printf("%s\n", "[SHIFT]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_CONTROL)
     printf("%s\n", "[CONTROL]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_ESCAPE)
     printf("%s\n", "[ESCAPE]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_END)
     printf("%s\n", "[END]");
     else if (key_stroke == VK_HOME)
     printf("%s\n", "[HOME]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_LEFT)
    printf("%s\n", "[LEFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_UP)
    printf("%s\n", "[UP]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_RIGHT)
    printf("%s\n", "[RIGHT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_DOWN)
    printf("%s\n", "[DOWN]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_DELETE)
    printf("%s\n", "[DEL]");
    else if (key_stroke == 190 || key_stroke == 110)
    printf("%s\n", ".");
    else
    printf("%s\n", &key_stroke);
    return 0;
 }
```